# lm-sensors not working on new Server

Tags: server, cpu, fan, lm-sensors

I have a new Server here freshly installed with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. After booting into the System the Fans get faster and faster until the spin at 100% it seems.

I've installed `lm-sensors` and ran `sensors-detect`, but it seems like it is not detected corretly. Here is the output of `sensors`:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +49.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +49.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +46.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +47.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +46.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 6:        +50.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 7:        +47.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

power_meter-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
power1:      260.00 W  (interval =   1.00 s)
```

There is no report of any RPM of the Fans.

Here is the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor       : 15
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 85
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4215R CPU @ 3.20GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 0x5003102
cpu MHz         : 1000.142
cache size      : 11264 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 16
core id         : 7
cpu cores       : 8
apicid          : 15
initial apicid  : 15
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 22
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req pku ospke avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
bugs            : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips        : 6400.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp` just shows `50000`

The `coretemp` module is the only module that got added by `sensors-detect` and is loaded which i verified by `lsmod` command.

Here is the info from `dmidecode -t 2` about the Mainboard:

```
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
        Product Name: S2600WF0
        Version: H87179-873
        Serial Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: Part Component
        Chassis Handle: 0x0000
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0
```

It feels like there is a module that is required for the sensors to work correctly, but i can't figure it out? Can anyone help?

Comment: Determine your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/89014/intel-server-board-s2600wf0/downloads.html to download the newer version. Report back.

Comment: It was the newest Version already. However it appears to be the BIOS Setting that sets the power mode. When this mode was set to "Performance" the Power Supply FANs went crazy. After setting it to Balace it just work like expectet with no performance difference.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed it.